# How is the serviceability of VOR unit part CI 215 checked?

Tags: vor

In the VOR receiver we use two antenna, which are joined with the help of an assembly (part # CI 215), then the output of these two antenna is fed to RxR.

My question is: how do we assure the serviceability of this unit (CI 215)?

1. Means coxial cable inner lead should short with outer OR Not.
2. Both antenna Fitting point short with each other OR Not.
3. coxial cable inner lead should short with both antenna Base fitting point OR Not.

Comment: I assume you are referring to a VOR receiver of a specific model, you might want to add the name of the model / part number.

Comment: If the VOR receiver receives a signal, then the antenna assembly is working.

Comment: Problems with my aircraft is, On VOR ferquency To/From flag dit not come remain NAV flag.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, and the question. Can you confirm you suspect the receiver is not fed with the antenna signal (possible problem with the antenna array, or the coaxial cables), and you are asking only about the wiring between antennas and receiver?